# Grey vertical line limiting the line length of my sourcecode in TeX Studio

Tags: texstudio

I don't know how it got there, but there is a grey line defining a 'new margin' in the place where I type my code. [image: Code1]
Also, when I want to type something in the existing text, the lines don't fill the entire length anymore, the last words just jump to a new line and start a new line, even if it is just one word. [image: Code2]
Compiling to pdf doesn't change, the pdf created looks just fine.

How can I get rid off this line? I want to use the whole space again and I want my lines to act normal.

Comment: Welcome to tex.SX

Comment: Menu `Options->Configure TeXstudio` check `Show advanced options` in the left lower corner  go to this tab and find `line wrapping` and select what you like.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what one can do

1. menu `Options->Configure TeXstudio`
2. check `Show advanced options`

[image]

3. find `line wrapping` and select from the list

[image]